# Problem with calculating winding number in sum of curves

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, plane-curves

Let
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma= \gamma_1 +\gamma_2+\gamma_3,\\
\gamma_1(t)=e^{it}, t\in[0,2\pi] \\
\gamma_2(t)=-1+2e^{-2it}, t\in [0,2\pi]\\
\gamma_3(t)=1-i+e^{it},t\in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{9\pi}{2}]
\end{align}
$$

Calculate the value of $n(\gamma,z)$ as $z$ takes its value in $\mathbb{C}\backslash\gamma^*.$

$\gamma^*$ is the interior of the closed curve.

My first problem is $\gamma$ as it seems that it is neither simple nor closed curve.
At first I tried defining $\gamma$ as 
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma(t)=\gamma_1(t)+\gamma_2(t), t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \\
\gamma(t)=\gamma_1(t)+\gamma_2(t)+\gamma_3(t), t\in[\frac{\pi}{2},2\pi] \\
\gamma(t)=\gamma_1(t)+\gamma_2(t)+\gamma_3(t), t\in[2\pi,\frac{9\pi}{2}] \\
\end{align}
$$
but that didn't work cause $\gamma(\frac{\pi}{2})$ had 2 different values and so did $\gamma(2\pi)$.

My second attempt was to "move" $\gamma_3$ so it would be applied at $2\pi$ , but that doesn't yield any results.

I am not sure that I followed the correct approach so any help , advice or guidance towards the right solution would be welcome.

Comment: $\gamma$ is a chain consisting of three closed curves (three circles, one traversed twice [clockwise], the others once [counterclockwise]). The "addition" is formal. For the winding number, you have $$n(\gamma,z) = n(\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3,z) = n(\gamma_1,z)+n(\gamma_2,z)+n(\gamma_3,z)$$ whenever $z$ lies on none of the curves.

Comment: I have a little question on notation: if the curve is $t\mapsto \gamma(t) = \gamma_1(t)+\gamma_2(t)+\gamma_3(t)$, where does $t$ live?

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for the clarification. One more question , how can I tell when $\gamma=...$ is a chain  and when is it used as I tried to?(never?)

Comment: @Avitus $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\gamma :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C} $ , though I am not sure if this helps